# Google Apps script For Needs

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

`I want to Add Start Trigger in Cell "N" for each row and want start time in cell "O" & also with this I want to Add Stop Trigger in Cell "P" for each row and want stop time in cell "Q" for all rows. And with This I want to automatically add Image Link From my G-drive in column "F" based on SKU Codes in column "E" for each specific SKU Codes.
[image: New Sheet in Which I want Above changes]

I tried the following Google apps script for these above changes which I want :-

1. For Start & Stop Triggers.
   [image: Apps script for Start & Stop Triggers]
   But I'm not getting my point I faced the below error.

Exception: This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added.
createTimeTriggers  @ Code.gs:15

2. For having Link for Photo from Drive.
   [image: Script For Image Url From Drive]

But I don't getting the result which I want.

So, I want the customisations which I listed Above`.

Comment: Kindly refrain from posting images of your spreadsheet and code blocks because [Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) and [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) can be utilized to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, when you edit the question, please ask one question at a time, as Stack Overflow's goal is to help users solve their problems and is not a bespoke coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to run functions using an installable onEdit function:

```
function name1() {
  Logger.log("name1");//Sample function
}

function name2() {
  Logger.log("name2");//Sample Function
}

function runFunctionByName(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry ")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    this[e.range.offset(0,1).getDisplayValue()]();//run function by name
  }
  e.range.setValue("FALSE");
}

function createRunFunctionByNameTrigger() {
  if( ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "runFunctionByName").length == 0 ) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("runFunctionByName").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```